# How do i get a html response to show in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Right i'm completely lost i have this getscores.php file

```
<?php

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password    //All This data is added on my live script 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name

// Create Connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

//Check connection
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}



// Retrieve data from database 
$result= $mysqli->query("SELECT query"); //this query is properly working in my live script too

echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black;"><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Score</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
// Start looping rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$rows['name'] . "</td><td>" . $rows['score'] . "</td>";
echo '</tr>';
// close while loop 
}

// close MySQL connection 
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

which returns a html table, what i want to do is display the table in wordpress, the script is called by [Click Here](http://f2syntax3rror.000webhostapp.com/getscores.php) so how do i actually get this to show in wordpress? i've tried putting the script in wordpress and that didn't work, i've tried using an iframe and calling on it there, i just really need some help because this is frazzling my brain

Comment: you can use $wpdb in wordpress, check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110677/get-results-using-wpdb

Comment: you could register this as a shortcode, and put that wherever you want

Comment: @charankumar where would i actually put this in on my wordpress though? just in the html section? i dont have any plugins as im on a free account

Comment: @F2 Syntax3rror on which page you want to display in the wordpress?

Comment: @Dolar what do you mean? where on the page do i put it?!? there's only a html or visual option, i am VERY new to word press so i need specifics really

Comment: You may put it on Post Page, Custom Post Page, Home Page etc. If you have website url then please add in comment so i will suggest you where you put it.

Comment: https://syntax3rror4wc.wordpress.com/ thats the website link but i dont just want to have a link to it, i want the html the call returns to be physically viewed on my page as a table @Dolar

Comment: I refer your website and found that you have 6 main page right? from it on which page you want to display the table? @F2 Syntax3error

Answer (score 0):

Treat the URL that you want to pull in the content from like it's an API request.

An XHR request in javascript will pull the content into an element on your actual page.

Something like this would work:
[How to use javascript to get information from the content of another page (same domain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850405/how-to-use-javascript-to-get-information-from-the-content-of-another-page-same)